# Were there any temples in Satya yuga?

Tags: gods, temple, worship, yuga, goddess

Is there any reference of temple of lord in the time of Satya Yuga?
Around that time people used to worship which God/Goddess?

Comment: I think various jyotirling were built in previous yuga's which may also be counted under satyuga because there were 4 more satyuga after ramayan happened so rameshwaram and vaidyanath jyotirling are available during that time.

SomNath ling was also in satyug.. but I cant say whether they were just ling form or in temple building.

Comment: Tirmala Tirupati is said to be extant since satya yuga. You must note that while the energies in kshetras and tirthas may have existed from time immemorial, the surrounding structures that house the deities/energy centres may have been constructed much later. Making this distinction is important.

Comment: @moonstar2001 then why there is no mention of temple worship in the Vedas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Devi BhAgavata PurAna, there were temples even in the Satya Yuga. See the following passage. It also addresses your other question:

> 31. Janamejaya said :-- “O Bhagavân! Describe particularly the details of the Yuga Dharma. I am now very desirous to hear which Dharma is for
>       which Yuga?” 32-54. Vyâsa said :-- O King! I will now show to you by
>       example the influence of the religion peculiar to each Yuga; hear it
>       attentively. O King! The hearts even of saints are quite disturbed by
>       the Yuga Dharma. See! Your father was a religious and high-souled
>       monarch; still the wicked Kâlî defiled his mind and prompted him to do
>       an act very insulting to a Brâhmana. Otherwise why would he, being a
>       renowned prince amongst the Ksattriyas and a descendant of Yayâti,
>       thus go and encircle a snake round the throat of an ascetic Brâhmin?
>       Therefore, O King! All actions are being influenced by the Yuga
>       Dharma. The Pundits, also recognise this. If you try your best to
>       perform any religious act, even then the Yuga Dharma would prevail,
>       yet you would be able to perform to a certain extent, a part of your
>       intention. O King! **In the Satya Yuga, the Brâhmins were versed in the
>       Vedas, always devoted to worship the Highest Force, with an ardent
>       desire to see the Devî; they were devoted to Gâyatrî with Pranava,
>       devoted to the meditation of Gâyatrî, always reciting silently
>       Gâyatrî, and the Mâyâvîja Mantram, the chief mantram. In every
>       village, the Brâhmins were very eager to erect temples of the Devî
>       Mahâ Mâyâ Ambikâ** and were truthful, merciful and pure and devoted to
>       their own respective works. The Ksattriyas, skilled in the science of
>       the highest knowledge, were ever engaged in doing things ordained by
>       the Vedas and were always intent in protecting well their subjects.
>       The Vais’yas did their cultivation and trade and the S’ûdras always
>       served the other three castes
>
> [**Devi BhAgavata PurAna- Book 6- Chapter 11**](http://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatam28.htm)

I have highlighted the relevant portions.

Comment: Bhagavatam says temple worship was started in Treta Yuga. https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/7/14/39