# Was every human a Vaishnava in Satya yuga?

Tags: vaishnavism, dharma, yuga

Satya Yuga is the first among the four yugas, where Dharma (religious principles) were followed to the perfection. Dharma can be found to be in perfect practice only in Rama Rajya and nowhere else. Naturally, we can deduce that the citizens of Rama Rajya are first class Vaishnavas, being devotees of Lord Ramachandra. Do we have any scriptural evidence supporting that every human was a Vaishnava in Krita Yuga?

Comment: No! Maharaja Sagar who ruled Bharatvarsha during 3rd charana of Satya yuga was devotee of Lord Shiva.

Comment: A Vaishnava is one who had taken the supreme personality of godhead as the ultimate goal of life. Vaishnavas like Arjuna have worshipped Lord Shiva. Just because he has worshipped Lord Shiva, we can't negate that Arjuna is not a Vaishnava. It's impossible that Sagara is not a Vaishnava. If he was not, why would Lord be born in him family line as Ramachandra. Please quote scriptural evidence saying that Sagara was *not* a Vaishnava.

Comment: Worshiping and being devotee, both are different IMHO! BTW check this article: https://medium.com/@srivarahamihira/royal-dynasties-of-satya-yuga-edd3efe56420

Comment: By the way, [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20338/277) provides good identification of Vaishnava. There should not be a matter of worshiping only particular deity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Srimad Bhagavatam, in Uddhava Gita of 11th Canto, Lord Krishna speaks these verses while describing varnashrama system.

> [SB 11.17.10](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/17/10) — In the beginning, in Satya-yuga, there is only one social class, called haṁsa, to which all human beings belong. In that age all people are unalloyed devotees of the Lord from birth, and thus learned scholars call this first age Kṛta-yuga, or the age in which all religious duties are perfectly fulfilled.
>
> [SB 11.17.11](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/17/11) — In Satya-yuga the undivided Veda is expressed by the syllable om, and I am the only object of mental activities. I become manifest as the four-legged bull of religion, and thus the inhabitants of Satya-yuga, fixed in austerity and free from all sins, worship Me as Lord Haṁsa.

This is generic trend in Satya yuga, there can be some exceptions always.

Comment: I suggest you improve your A with the information who is that "I" and "Me" in the quoted verses. *... and I am the only object of mental activities. I become manifest as ...* Also explain what is "SB".

Comment: You did not answer the question.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu the answer is self explanatory, if you need any specific clarifications, you can add a comment.

Answer (score 4):

How can that be possible? For example, for any Dvija, it is mandatory to worship Goddess Gayatri who is nothing but an aspect of Adi Parashakti. So, any Dvija will be Shakta first before being something else. And this remains the same irrespective of which Yuga it is.

Moreover, Ramayana did not happen in Satya Yuga like you think. It occurred in Treta Yuga when lot of corruptions already crept in. People during Treta were not as pure as those who lived in Satya Yuga.

Also, in this case different Puranas might make different claims. For example, as shown in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24571/4732), the Devi Bhagavatam says all people were primarily worshipers of Mahadevi (Parashakti) in the Satya Yuga.

> Janamejaya said :-- “O Bhagavân! Describe particularly the details of
>   the Yuga Dharma. I am now very desirous to hear which Dharma is for
>   which Yuga?” 32-54. Vyâsa said :-- O King! I will now show to you by
>   example the influence of the religion peculiar to each Yuga; hear it
>   attentively. O King! The hearts even of saints are quite disturbed by
>   the Yuga Dharma. See! Your father was a religious and high-souled
>   monarch; still the wicked Kâlî defiled his mind and prompted him to do
>   an act very insulting to a Brâhmana. Otherwise why would he, being a
>   renowned prince amongst the Ksattriyas and a descendant of Yayâti,
>   thus go and encircle a snake round the throat of an ascetic Brâhmin?
>   Therefore, O King! All actions are being influenced by the Yuga
>   Dharma. The Pundits, also recognise this. If you try your best to
>   perform any religious act, even then the Yuga Dharma would prevail,
>   yet you would be able to perform to a certain extent, a part of your
>   intention. O King! **In the Satya Yuga, the Brâhmins were versed in
>   the Vedas, always devoted to worship the Highest Force, with an ardent
>   desire to see the Devî; they were devoted to Gâyatrî with Pranava,
>   devoted to the meditation of Gâyatrî, always reciting silently
>   Gâyatrî, and the Mâyâvîja Mantram, the chief mantram. In every
>   village, the Brâhmins were very eager to erect temples of the Devî
>   Mahâ Mâyâ Ambikâ and were truthful, merciful and pure and devoted to
>   their own respective works.** The Ksattriyas, skilled in the science
>   of the highest knowledge, were ever engaged in doing things ordained
>   by the Vedas and were always intent in protecting well their subjects.
>   The Vais’yas did their cultivation and trade and the S’ûdras always
>   served the other three castes

[**Source - Devi Bhagavatam Book 6, Chapter 11.**](http://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatam28.htm)

Comment: OP didn't say Ramayana happened in Satya Yuga. He said Dharma flourished in that Yuga just like Satya Yuga and people were Vaishnavas (Dharmic).

Comment: Your answer assumes that Vaishnavas do not sincerely worship Devi or chant Gayatri mantra. Ramanujacharya, Madhvacharya, etc, were first class Brahmanas initiated in Gayatri mantra. Worship of Devi is not exclusive from worship of Hari, it is inclusive. A person who worships Hari, automatically worships all the gods and satisfies all of them perfectly, as explained by Krishna in Gita. Of course, one may choose to separately offer respectful worship to Devi, the potency of Krishna, as per Upasana Kanda and thereby indirectly worshipping Keshava.

Comment: Anyone who is completely surrendered unto Mukunda, is freed from debts to all gods and ancestors. As pouring water on the root of a tree energizes the trunk, branches, twigs, and everything else, simply worshipping the supreme personality of godhead, automatically satisfies all gods, who are parts of him.

Comment: Srimad Bhagavatham asserts that the pure devotees of Lord Vishnu develop all the good qualities of devas, while those who are not devotees of Krishna have no good qualities at all. Therefore, it is natural that they perfectly follow religious principles.

Comment: Lord Ramachandra appeared in the end Treta Yuga age and re-established Satya Yuga in his kingdom. At least in Rama Rajya, in contrast to Lanka Rajya ruled by Ravana, people were as pure as Satya Yuga or even more, because they are under the direct rule of the supreme personality of godhead and more importantly they were fully devoted to him.

Comment: You seem to already know the answer. So, for what reason u hv asked the question here? @SridharJammalamadaka

Comment: Whatever u are saying are Vaishnava beliefs.. those things are for them to follow only. Others have other beliefs @SridharJammalamadaka

Comment: In Srimad Bhagavatham, it is not mentioned that these statements are applicable / to be followed by a sect of people in a geography, etc. Vedic knowledge is applicable for every living entity. The author of Srimad Bhagavatham and Devi Bhagavatham are the same person, who again is an incarnation of Vishnu.

Comment: Bhagavata Purana is a Purana.. It is not Veda... As I hv said what ever you are saying in comments are Vaishnava beliefs other sects hv other beliefs to follow .. In Rig Vedokta Devi Sukta it is clearly said that all Havis eventually reach Paradevi and all worships are meant for her only... Also any Dvija is a Shakta first then anything else as my answer says... And, Devi Bhagavatam clearly says that in Satya Yuga everyone primarily used to worship the highest Devi.. so, now it's upto u wht to believe and wht not to @SridharJammalamadaka

Comment: If we reject puranas like Srimad Bhagavatham, and Devi Bhagavatham, where can we get light in the dense darkness of Kali Yuga?

Comment: Since you have quoted Devi Bhagavatham, I'm sure you believe in it and you might have read Radha Krishna tattvam explained in it.

Comment: The highest of all these Tattvas is of course the Lalita Tattva.. all the other deities, which ever it is, sit at her feet .. also you hv asked a question and I hv answered it... thr should it end.. I'm not interested in having a debate or discussion with u. You are free to believe anything that does not bother me. @SridharJammalamadaka

Comment: Gita quote: "Fools deride Me when I descend in the human form. They do not know My transcendental nature and My supreme dominion over all that be."

Comment: @SridharJammalamadaka Just like Vaishnavas have their way of explaining, other sects have their way of explaining. So it is not appropriate at least on this site to try to prove superiority over others. It is advisable to write an answer instead explaining how vaishnavites view rather than arguing back and forth. Such questions can be asked like how vaishnavas view certain verse which goes against general Vaishnava opinion.

Comment: @SridharJammalamadaka - How many souls are there in this planet Earth, that much way is there to return back. Supreme's Maya is so powerful as he can delude us and at the same time, help us in reaching him....So no pointing in debate of superiority but instead start following what is prescribed for you. That alone will take you closer to Paramatma

Comment: The monent you reject interpolated texts and altered puranas you will move towards self illumination or swa prakAsha.

Comment: @Rakesh Joshi, those who have already got self illumination sincerely follow the sattvika puranas.

Comment: Those who hv got self illumination do not any longer rely on reading books.... So u are gradually coming to ur point? @SridharJammalamadaka

Comment: I said "follow", not read. In Bhagavad Gita, Krishna says that those who come to him even for material benefits are *sukritina* or pious and those who take to devotional service of Krishna with great faith are the topmost yogis. On the contrary, he says that those who don't take to him are grossly foolish and lowest of mankind, what to talk about self illumination.

Comment: Follow or read both the same thing in the context.Those who are self realized are like rulers whatever they do become rules, whtever they say become scriptures. Following something is for the ordinary persons (slavish) to do. Also again u are talking about Vaishnava beliefs.. Not everyone will follow those. @SridharJammalamadaka

Comment: Every living entity is an eternal servant of the God, whether realised or not. Being captured by Maya, one thinks that one is a ruler or will become one in the future. The peak of illusion is that when a living entity aims to become the God, Lord of Maya. Any sober person, not deluded by scholarly "beliefs" understands this wisdom.

Comment: Every living entity is an eternal **servant** of the God,   -- That is again a Vaishnava belief.. Not every Sadhakas believe that they are servants'slaves.. they are powerful Upasakas ... Btw You can leave it not interested any more... @SridharJammalamadaka