# Did the worship of Adi Parashakti come in the later Yugas?

Tags: vishnu, nara-narayana

I have heard that in the Satya Yuga only Narayana was worshipped although there were devatas. Here I'm talking about the supreme God. Is it Narayana or Adi Parashakti? It can't be both I'm sure.

Comment: You can have a small look here: [Vedic and Puranic Supreme God](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43915/20129)

Comment: You can check the answer under this post: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18112/were-there-any-temples-in-satya-yuga